# I have to somehow type https:// explicitly when chrome returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: macos, google-chrome, http, https, osx-yosemite

Sometimes chrome returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when I click on a link. And when I take the url (which did not have http or https specified) and put "https://" in front it works.

One place that consistently do this is

"productforums.google.com/forum/#!overview"
vs.
"https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!overview"

I feel like I must have somehow toggled a configuration wrong on my mac preventing it to try https when http fail or vice versa. Or something like that... Or perhaps this is a normal behavior. If this is something wrong with my configuration where can I set this on mac?

p.s. I am a mac user. (Early 2013 MBA recently installed Yosemite)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be related to some configuration changes in your system. It has been handled via code @ line #856 of http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!overview.

```
 window.location.href = "https://productforums.google.com/forum/" + window.location.hash;
```

Here it sends another request to the https version of the page. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE is returned when server closes the connection and responds with no content to the browser. However, there are chances of:

- some incorrect / unsecure proxy handling the requests before it reaches server.
- some incorrect / unsecure proxy handling the requests before it reaches you (browser).
- any firewall setting which is terminating the connection before it reaches browser.

Try to connect via any other network and/or try to connect using any other system in the same network. Else reset your browser or firewall settings and retry.

Answer (score 0):

I also experience this behavior on a 2015 MBP (and also in Firefox or Safari). While switching to HTTPS works, if the website supports it, I am able to access the page via curl at the command line:

`curl http://calendar.google.com`

I'm a relatively new Mac user but this suggests to me that another layer is the problem other than the network.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in all browsers: firefox, chrome, safari; but only with specific websites (sldn.softlayer.com, docs.ansible.com, and infrequently google search results). Late 2013 MBP, OSX Yosemite 10.10.5. Sometimes prefixing with "https://" helps, sometimes it doesn't.

But I've noticed the issue only happens when I am connected to work using the Cisco Anyconnect VPN client - not sure if that provides any useful troubleshooting info, it is an annoying problem.